# Why can't TypeScript recognise installed TypeScript node_modules?

Tags: typescript

This problem has long bothered me but I am at a loss as to why. I seem to always be fighting with `node_modules`. This isn't a `@types` issue.  I am trying to use TypeScript NPM Libraries which already have types.

A great example of this is font awesome. I follow the guide.

`npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core --save`

It tell me that I should then go ahead and configure it using this syntax.

```
import { library, dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
```

To which TypeScript informs me that this isn't a module.

I always have to resort to dirty paths like this:

```
import { library, dom } from '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/index';
```

Why does this work for everyone apart from myself?

Here is my `tsconfig`

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "declaration": false,
        "declarationMap": false,
        "diagnostics": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "strict": false
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try adding `"moduleResolution": "node"` to `compilerOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `"module": "es6"` setting you have ES6 module generation. If your `module` is not `node`, TypeScript will default to `Classic` for module resolution. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html -- which explains how Classic and Node module resolution work. You want `"moduleResolution": "node"` to import from `node_modules` the way you want.

You actually don't need `module` since `target: ES5` will make `module` default to `es6`. You might want to revisit your setting for `target`.